# What is the point of Raw weapons?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I know that in Dark Souls 2, you can infuse weapons to make them do elemental damage, but what does Raw do? Does it just increase damage? If not, what else does it do? Also, would it be worth it to Raw a Great Club, or is there a better option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Raw weapons greatly increase the base damage of the weapon and removes any scaling it had.

The point of this infusion is to improve the damage of weapons withouth scaling for builds that have the minimun stat to use the weapon and focuses on other stats that tend not to scale like health and resistance.

The same is applied for Dark Souls (1).

If you aren't pumping your strength it could be a good infusion you would lose that B scaling but wouldn't be a great inconvenience.

Comment: Would it be worth it to infuse it with something like poison or bleed or is that a waste of time and souls?

Comment: Poison and bleed scale off of Dexterity and Adaptability and are anyway best used with fast weapons, because it builds up the Poison/Bleed status effect faster. A popular build at launch was maximum tank/Adaptability with two poison/bleed Cestuses. It is a good idea, just make sure you use a weapon that is fast. Also, Raw is best used on weapons that already have high base damage without any scaling.

Comment: ok that makes sense. So raw would be good on the drangleic sword for example

Comment: Sort of, usually people pick the most damaging weapons available without upgrades (usually Great Hammers or Axes). Other examples include the Old Knight Hammer and Smelter Hammer. You will not be getting any scaling so you want your base damage to be as high as possible. Also to consider when you make a character designed for Raw weapons is how many stats are you willing to put into STR/DEX or whatever to use the weapon before it becomes a loss? Remember you want all your points in defensive stats if possible. So you want a weapon with high base damage and low requirements.

Comment: Cont. -- To compare to the Great Club which you mentioned in your OP, that would not be a good choice because the Great and Large Clubs are best used with STR specialist characters. They are good at scaling. Usually weapons with high scaling have less than optimal base damage and vice versa.